# D-Link Dir-300 "Access Point" Mode or Bridge?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, bridge

I'm currently exploring the possibilities of installing an old router I found in the basement (the D-Link Dir-300) as an access point in order to get more WiFi coverage and also connect things like the living room tv via ethernet instead of WiFi in hopes of making the connection more stable.

When researching about this topic I got different and therefore confusing results. A lot of people recommend setting up the D-Link with a fixed IP, which should be in the same network of my router. Also I'd have to turn off settings like NAT, UPnP and DHCP and give the WiFi the same SSID and Password for it to work. This is called bridging, from what I read I guess, right? Even the official user manual of the D-Link Dir-300 describes setting up an Access Point in that manner.

However, on the web interface for configuring the D-Links settings, there is a checkbox called "Access Point" Mode, which is never talked about. Neither in the internet tutorials nor in the user manual.

I'm now confused weither this is implicitly doing the same thing as in the (let's call it manual) bridging I described above or if this is something else altogether? Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A lot of people recommend setting up the D-Link with a fixed IP, which should be in the same network of my router. Also I'd have to turn off settings like NAT, UPnP and DHCP and give the WiFi the same SSID and Password for it to work. This is called bridging, from what I read I guess, right?

Yes. Well – the "bridge" is already there; in nearly all home routers, all "LAN" Ethernet ports are already bridged together, and they're also bridged with the Wi-Fi access point. So the first step, turning off UPnP and DHCP Server, just disables things that could *interfere* with using the D-Link as a bridge.

However, these changes do not affect the 'WAN' port – there's still a router between it and the LAN bridge. Even if you disable NAT, that doesn't actually disable WAN↔LAN routing *in general* (NAT is an "extra" feature), so using the WAN port as uplink wouldn't give you a bridged network. (That is why people specifically talk about "LAN-LAN" connections, etc.)

So – (**this is a guess because I do not have a D-Link nearby**) – I suspect that enabling "Access point mode" additionally *bridges the WAN port* as part of the main LAN bridge, so that you get one extra Ethernet port (and with a more suitable colour). After all, an access point does not have any need for routing.

To find out whether that's the case or not,

1. connect directly to your existing router and note the MAC address of the default gateway (say from the `arp -a` command, or even from Wireshark);
2. activate the "access point" mode in the D-Link, and (if you cannot test with wired Ethernet) temporarily set it to a *different* SSID than the main network;
3. connect the D-Link's WAN port to your existing router;
4. connect the computer to the D-Link, make sure the computer still successfully configures the same IP address as with your main router, and make sure you have Internet access;
5. again use `arp -a` to look at what MAC address is shown for the default gateway.

If the MAC addresses in first and last steps match, then you do have the WAN port bridged to the rest.

Comment: Checked it, and it's excactly like you described it. Thanks!